# How can I use a string representation of an enum in a Jest test.each case?

Tags: enums, jestjs

When writing a Jest `test.each()` test using an enum like below

```
enum MyEnum {
    FirstValue,
    SecondValue,
    ThirdValue
}

describe('my example', () => {
    test.each([MyEnum.FirstValue, MyEnum.SecondValue, MyEnum.ThirdValue])(
        '%o',
        (input: MyEnum) => {
            expect(input).toBeDefined();
        }
    );
});
```

The output text is:

```
my example
  0
  1
  2
```

I would like it to be

```
my example
  FirstValue
  SecondValue
  ThirdValue
```

Using other formatting parameters like `%p` or `%j` like listed in the [Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout) don't change anything

Answer (score 2):

I just thought of an answer, I could use `describe.each` in stead:

```
describe.each(testcases)('my test', (input: MyEnum) => {
    test(`${MyEnum[input]}`, () => {
        expect(input).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert enun to array, to avoid hardcore it and add it to each

```
enum MyEnum {
    FirstValue,
    SecondValue,
    ThirdValue
}

describe('my example', () => {
let myEnum: string[] = Object.keys(MyEnum);
    test.each(myEnum)('my enum %p', (enum) => {
            expect(enum).toBeDefined();
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Yeah, but then I'ld have to convert the string back to an enum value before I can use it in method calls.

Comment: You can Cast <MyEnun>enun